# Sending Analytics events from react component

Tags: reactjs, redux, web-analytics

What is the right way to send analytics events from React components? Currently, if I send it from a component render method the events get sent multiple times because the component re-renders multiple times because of setState call.  And If I try to set a state flag after sending a analytics event to avoid multiple event sending the warning for setState

> "Cannot update during an existing state transition"

Comment: At what point during the lifecycle of your component do you want to send the information? Before/after each update?

Comment: Currently, I have a component which has a conditional render based on a redux state value. And I'm sending analytics events inside those conditional renders.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set the component state, don't do it during the render process, or you will face the exact error you are seeing.

Instead, do it in [`comopnentWillReceiveProps()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops). There you can freely set the state before the actual rendering is started.

Two things to keep in mind, though:

- This method will be always be executed independently of the outcome of [`shouldComponentUpdate()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) in case you have implemented it.
- It will *not* be executed if only the component state changes, only a change to the comonent props will trigger it.